# how can i perform onclick action on listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

```
   I have designed a custom listview. In that view i have one textview and two edittext fields. when i am clicking on the individual rows in listview that perform another activity(i.e another page will open). But i cannot perform onclick action on my listview.
```

i have wrote some code but its not working. i have shown that code as below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.sharefolioedit);

       getList();
           lv.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
            lv = getListView();
    lv.setClickable(true);
             lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView,
      int position, long id) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryList.this,AddSubCategoryList.class);
      startActivity(intent);

      }

       }
```

Comment: Are you missing a `}`? I see 3 opening brackets but only 2 closing ones...

Comment: so is there some logcat output? add some Log.d("Debug","..") entries to your code to see which lines are executed and which not. i can say that onclick on listviews works nice in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me :

```
this.setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener ( new AdapterView. OnItemClickListener ( )
{
    public void onItemClick ( AdapterView <?> aView, View v, int position, long id )
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryList.this,AddSubCategoryList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: but in my code above code is not working. i.e i unable to click on the listview. the listview not supported to onclick action.

Comment: print some variable in onItemClick() method and check LogCat view to check whether the method is executing or not.